# How to Notarize an executable shell script (.command) file for MacOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, macos-catalina, notarize

This is a DIFFERENT scenario than discussed in other postings:

I have a .sh (shell script) which I've changed to a .command (executable shell script).  It's signed using code sign, and being distributed on a .dmg that is signed.

However, Catalina (of course) doesn't like it -- complains it "can't be opened because Apple can't check it for malicious software".  The user can still open the .command file if they right-click and select "Open" from the context menu, but the alert is still displayed, although this time with an available Open button.

I'd really like to avoid having to create a simple command line APPLICATION just for the purpose of executing a few shell script lines -- just so it can be notarized.

Anyone know of how to get around this?

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Your going to hate this but throw it into a `.app` bundle and call it from the `.plist` as the exec.  Then you may proceed with notarization.

Comment: Yeah, that seems kinda kludgy.  Maybe I better file a support question with Developer Tech Support and see if they have any better ideas.

Comment: Welcome to the island.